# Int comparison in bash error

Tags: bash

I'm trying to compare the left values of two IP adresses, but i get an error:

> ":a : int expected..."

Here is the code:

```
IN="195.152.15.1"
IFS='.' read -ra ADDR <<< "$IN"

IN2="196.151.14.1"
IFS='.' read -ra ADDR2 <<< "$IN2"

a=${ADDR[0]}
b=${ADDR2[0]}

if [ a -eq b ]
then
echo "OK"
fi
```

I tried several combinations but nothing works, any suggestion ?

p.s: i don't want to use the "=" sign, only the "-eq"

Comment: you want to say `if [ "$a" -eq "$b" ]`. That is, you are missing the dollar sign to refer to the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has been solved in the comments. You need to refer to the variables in the comparison:

```
if [ "$a" -eq "$b" ]
then
    echo "OK"
fi
```

Quotes around variables are always recommended when using `[`. With bash, you've got a couple of alternatives:

```
if [[ $a -eq $b ]] # extended test is smart enough to deal with unquoted variables
if (( a == b )) # inside arithmetic context, a and b unambiguously refer to variables
```

I've heard that the performance of `((` is slightly worse than the other options but I doubt that it's significant enough to worry about.

It's worth mentioning that `ALL_CAPS` variable names should be avoided in scripts as they are for use by the shell. Also, there's no need to read into an array if you only want the first part of each IP:

```
IFS=. read -r ip1 junk <<< "$in1"
```

The rest of the line is written to the variable `junk`, which can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

change `if [ a -eq b ]` to `if [ $a -eq $b ]`